# Automatically Turn a Toggle On and Off in Max MSP

Tags: max, max-msp-jitter

[image]

How do I automatically turn a toggle on and off in Max MSP? For instance, if I want this toggle to print out this message for 30 seconds, and then stop printing for 30 seconds, and then on and off again by itself for a set period of time without me manually adjusting it, what should I do?

Answer (score 0):

To turn a toggle on or off every 30 seconds, you can connect it to the output of a `[metro 30000]` object.